# Firefox WebExtension - Fetch page HTML with browser credentials

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I've made a web extension for Firefox and it's dependent on the user of a certain website being logged in for it to work, since it delivers notifications. The problem is that the extension cannot detect the user being logged in when 3rd party cookies are blocked in Firefox's options.

Manifest.json:

```
"permissions": [
    "https://www.example.com/",
    "storage",
    "sessions",
    "cookies"
],
```

Code:

```
fetch('https://www.example.com/messages/', {
    credentials: 'include',
    method: "GET"
}).then(response => {
    return response.text()
}).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Error:

```
Request to access cookie or storage on “<URL>” was blocked because we are blocking all third-party storage access requests and content blocking is enabled.
```

Comment: You didn't show where this code runs so I guess it's a content script. Perform the request in the background script or in the browser_action script.

Comment: It is in background.js, the website still acts as though the user is not logged in.

Comment: Oh I remember now, both Greasemonkey and Violentmonkey use browser.cookies API to send the `cookie` header manually via browser.webRequest API, see their source code.